# Android Data Binding build.gradle syncing prob?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-databinding

For databinding

1) I have added

```
android {
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
```

to my project `build.gradle`, but this error occurs:

```
Error:(5, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'dataBinding()'
Possible causes:

.The project 'exampleDatabinding' may be using a version of Gradle that does    
not contain the method.
Gradle settings

.The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.

Apply Gradle plugin
```

2) Then I added:

`apply plugin: "com.android.databinding"` (to project `build.gradle`)

and `classpath "com.android.databinding:dataBinder:1.0-rc1"`  (to project `build.gradle`)

But the same error occured.

Comment: Are you using the Gradle 1.5.0-alpha1 plugin? Else, you could try the older implementation method, by adding in project gradle:`classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0"` &`classpath "com.android.databinding:dataBinder:1.0-rc4"`, in your app gradle file, n the top, before `android{}` : `apply plugin: "com.android.databinding"`

Comment: And maybe check what Gradle version you use, if necessary update it to Gradle 2.4.

Answer (score 6):

In the file build.gradle of the project add the dependency

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0-beta2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
```

And in the file build.gradle of the module include the dataBinding section:

```
android{
  ...
  dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
  ...
}
```

The versions of build.gradle can be found here: [Versions](https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/)

Answer (score 1):

The project 'exampleDatabinding' may be using a version of Gradle that does
not contain the method.

You need to update your gradle to latest version 2.10
To update gradle do as follows
YourProject->gradle->wrapper->gradle-wrapper.properties

update the distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.

Also add dataBinding:

```
android{
  ...
  dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
  ...
}
```

Also update your classpath:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'

    }
}
```